# Set alternate log file for iptables with syslog-ng

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, logging, syslog-ng

Does anyone know how to set an alternate logging file for iptables with syslog-ng on Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to use some log prefix in iptables with the --log-prefix option and match against that prefix in syslog-ng.

Here's a link with more information and examples: http://www.masquerade.cz/en/logovani-iptables-trizeni-logu/